# Pygame, rotation around center makes the image disappear

Tags: python, pygame, rotation, center

I cannot understand why, when I try to rotate it around its center, my projectile disappear.
Rotating it not around its center has no problem. I try to show the coordonates of its center, and it seems fine. Thanks for any help.
Here's the methode for rotation, in the "projectile" script.

```
    def rotate(self):
        # Tourner le projectile
        self.angle += 2
        self.image = pg.transform.rotozoom(self.origin_image, self.angle, 1)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = self.rect.center)
```

Main :

```
"""
Created on Mon Jun 14 09:54:56 2021

@author: Graven
"""

import pygame as pg
import math
from game import Game


pg.init()  # charger les composants de pygame

clock = pg.time.Clock()           

# Générer la fenêtre du jeu
screenSize = (1080, 720)
pg.display.set_caption('Comet fall game')  #(title, icontitle)  Définir le titre de la fenêtre
screen = pg.display.set_mode(screenSize)  # (size, flag...) taille de la fenêtre

# Importer l'arrière plan
background = pg.image.load('assets/bg.jpg')

# Importer la bannière
banner = pg.image.load('assets/banner.png')
banner = pg.transform.scale(banner, (500, 500))
banner_rect = banner.get_rect()
banner_rect.x = math.ceil(screen.get_width() / 4)
# importerle bouton pour lancer la partie
play_button = pg.image.load('assets/button.png')
play_button = pg.transform.scale(play_button, (400, 150))
play_button_rect = play_button.get_rect()
play_button_rect.x = math.ceil(screen.get_width() / 3.33)
play_button_rect.y = math.ceil(screen.get_height() / 2)


# Charger le jeu
game = Game()
running = True  # jeu en cours d'execution

# Boucle tant que running est vrai
while running :
    # pg.time.delay(10)
    # Appliquer l'arrière plan du jeu
    screen.blit(background, (-1000, -200))  # injecter l'image sur l'écran


    # Vérifier si notre jeu a commencé ou non
    if game.is_playing:
        # Déclencher les instructions de la partie
        game.update(screen, screenSize) 
          
    # Vérifier si le jeu n'a pas encore commencé 
    else :
        # Ajouter l'écran de bienvenue
        screen.blit(play_button, play_button_rect)
        screen.blit(banner,banner_rect)

            
    # mettre à jour l'écran
    pg.display.flip() 
    # clock.tick(1000)
    
    # si le joueur ferme cette fenetre ou click sur start
    for event in pg.event.get():  # reprendre tous les évenements possibles
        # vérifier que l'evenement est fermeture de fenetre
        if event.type == pg.QUIT :
            running = False
            pg.quit()
        elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            # Vérification pour savoir si le curseur est en collision avec le boutton
            if play_button_rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                # mettre le jeu en mode "lancé"
                game.start()
```

Game :

```
"""
Created on Mon Jun 14 10:40:05 2021

@author: Graven
"""
import pygame as pg
from player import Player
from monster import Monster
clock = pg.time.Clock()  
# Créer une seconde classe qui représente le jeu
class Game :
    def __init__(self):
        # Définir si le jeu a commencé ou non
        self.is_playing = False
        # Générer notre joueur
        self.all_players = pg.sprite.Group()  # Uniquement pour la fonction collision qui vérifie un sprite avec un groupe
        self.player = Player(self)
        self.all_players.add(self.player)
        # Enregistrer toutes les touches actionnées   
        self.pressed = {}
        # Groupe de monstre
        self.all_monsters = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.k=0
    
    def start(self):
        # lors d'une nouvelle partie, respawn des monstres
        self.is_playing = True
        # self.spawn_monster()
        # self.spawn_monster()
    
    def game_over(self):
        # Remettre le jeu à neuf, retirer les monstres, remettre 100 pv et jeu en attente
        self.all_monsters = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.player.health = self.player.max_health
        self.is_playing = False
        
    def update(self, screen, screenSize):
        # Appliquer l'image du joueur
        screen.blit(self.player.image, self.player.rect)
        # Visualiser la barre de vie du joueur
        self.player.update_health_bar(screen, self.player.chargeState)
        # Récupérer les projectiles du joueur
        for projectile in self.player.all_projectile:
            projectile.move()
        # Récupérer les monstres du jeu
        for monster in self.all_monsters:
            monster.forward()
            monster.update_health_bar(screen)
            
            
        # Appliquer l'ensemble des images de mon groupe de projectiles
        self.player.all_projectile.draw(screen)
        # Appliquer l'ensemble des images de mon groupe de monstre
        self.all_monsters.draw(screen)
        # Charge du projectile
        if self.player.charge_projectile:
            self.player.chargeState += 1
        else:
            self.player.chargeState = 0

        
        # Vérifier si le joueur souhaite se déplacer
        if self.pressed.get(pg.K_RIGHT) and self.player.rect.x < screenSize[0] - self.player.rect.width:
            self.player.move_right()
            
        elif self.pressed.get(pg.K_LEFT) and self.player.rect.x > 0:
            self.player.move_left()
            
 
        # si le joueur réalise un évenement
        for event in pg.event.get():  # reprendre tous les évenements possibles
            # vérifier que l'evenement est fermeture de fenetre
            if event.type == pg.QUIT :
                pg.quit()  
            # Détecter si un joueur lache une touche du clavier
            elif event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                self.pressed[event.key] = True                
                # Détecter si espace est enclenché pour lancer le projectile
                if event.key == pg.K_SPACE:
                    self.player.charge_projectile = True
            elif event.type == pg.KEYUP and self.player.charge_projectile :
                self.player.launch_projectile()
                self.player.charge_projectile = False
                self.pressed[event.key] = False
            elif event.type == pg.KEYUP :
                self.pressed[event.key] = False
        # self.k += 1
        # print(self.k, self.pressed)

    
    def check_collision(self, sprite, group):
        return pg.sprite.spritecollide(sprite, group, False, pg.sprite.collide_mask)
    
    def spawn_monster(self):
        monster = Monster(self)
        self.all_monsters.add(monster)
```

Player :

```
"""
Created on Mon Jun 14 10:39:16 2021

@author: Graven
"""
import pygame as pg
from projectile import Projectile


# Créer une première classe qui représente le joueur
class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite) :
    def __init__(self, game):
        super().__init__()
        self.game = game
        self.health = 100
        self.max_health = 100
        self.chargeState = 0
        self.attack =  0.5
        self.max_charge = 100
        self.velocity = 3  
        self.image = pg.image.load('assets/player.png')
        self.rect =  self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = 450
        self.rect.y = 500
        self.all_projectile = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.charge_projectile = False
        
        
    def damage(self, amout):
        self.health -= amout
        if self.health <= 0 :
            self.game.game_over()
        
    def move_right(self):
        # si le joueur n'est pas en collision avec un monstre
        if not self.game.check_collision(self, self.game.all_monsters):
            self.rect.x += self.velocity
    def move_left(self):
        self.rect.x -= self.velocity
        
    def launch_projectile(self):
        # Créer une nouvelle instance de la classe projectile
        self.all_projectile.add(Projectile(self))
        
    
    def update_health_bar(self, surface, max_charge):
        # Définir une couleur pour la jauge de vie(vert) et son arrière plan (gris)
        if max_charge <  self.max_charge :
            bar_color = (111, 210, 46)
        else:
            bar_color = (255, 128, 0)
        back_bar_color = (60, 63,60)
        # Définir la position de la jauge de vie et sa largeur/épaisseur
        bar_position = [self.rect.x +50, self.rect.y + 20, self.health, 7]        # Définir la position de l'arrière plan dela jauge
        back_bar_position = [self.rect.x + 50, self.rect.y + 20, self.max_health, 7]
        # Dessiner la barre de vie
        pg.draw.rect(surface, back_bar_color, back_bar_position)
        pg.draw.rect(surface, bar_color, bar_position)
```

Monster

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Mon Jun 14 18:48:46 2021

@author: Graven
"""

import pygame as pg
import random


# Création d'une classe qui gère la notion de monstre
class Monster(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game):
        self.game = game
        super().__init__()
        self.max_health = 60 + random.randint(0,60) 
        self.health = self.max_health
        self.attack = 0.3
        self.image = pg.image.load('assets/mummy.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = 1080 + random.randint(0, 300)
        self.rect.y = 540
        self.velocity = random.randint(1,3)
    
    def damage(self, amount):
        self.health -= amount
        if self.health <= 0 :
            # Réapparaitre comme un nouveau monstre
            self.rect.x = 1080 + random.randint(0, 300)
            self.max_health = 60 + random.randint(0,60) 
            self.health = self.max_health
            self.velocity = random.randint(1,3)
        
    def update_health_bar(self, surface):
        # Définir une couleur pour la jauge de vie(vert) et son arrière plan (gris)
        bar_color, back_bar_color = (111, 210, 46), (60, 63,60)
        # Définir la position de la jauge de vie et sa largeur/épaisseur
        bar_position = [self.rect.x + 10, self.rect.y - 20, self.health, 5]
        # Définir la position de l'arrière plan dela jauge
        back_bar_position = [self.rect.x + 10, self.rect.y - 20, self.max_health, 5]

        # Dessiner la barre de vie
        pg.draw.rect(surface, back_bar_color, back_bar_position)
        pg.draw.rect(surface, bar_color, bar_position)
        
        
    def forward(self):
        # si le monster n'est pas en collision avec le joueur
        if not self.game.check_collision(self, self.game.all_players):
            self.rect.x -= self.velocity
        else:
            # Si le monstre est en collision avec le joueur, inflige des degats
            self.game.player.damage(self.attack)
```

Projectile :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Mon Jun 14 11:41:52 2021

@author: Graven
"""

import pygame as pg
# définir la classe qui gère le projectile de notre joueur
class Projectile(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    
    #définir le constructeur
    def __init__(self, player):
        super().__init__()
        self.velocity = 5
        self.player = player
        self.image = pg.image.load('assets/projectile.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.damage = int(self.player.attack * min(self.player.chargeState, self.player.max_charge)**1.1)
        self.image = pg.transform.scale(self.image, (self.damage, self.damage))
        self.rect.x = player.rect.x + 95
        self.rect.y = player.rect.y + 115 - self.damage/2
        self.origin_image = self.image
        self.angle = 0
        
        
    def rotate(self):
        # Tourner le projectile
        self.angle += 2
        self.image = pg.transform.rotozoom(self.origin_image, self.angle, 1)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = self.rect.center)

        
    def remove(self):
        self.player.all_projectile.remove(self)
        
    def move(self):
        self.rect.x += self.velocity
#        self.rotate()
#        centre_proj = self.rect.center
#        print('centre_proj',centre_proj)
        
        # Vérifier su le projectile entre en collision avec un monstre
        for monstre_rencontre in  self.player.game.check_collision(self, self.player.game.all_monsters):
            # Attribuer les dégats
            monstre_rencontre.damage(self.damage)

            
            #supprimer le projectile
            self.remove()
        # Vérifier si le projectie n'est plus présent sur l'écran
        if self.rect.x > 1080:
            # Supprimer le projectile
            self.remove()
```

Comment: The projectile has a square png image. It should rotate on itself and moving straght when the player shoots. 
projectile is an object with a fireball image. I would like to go straight. So it must rotate around the centre of its rectangle I guess.

Comment: The size of the image seems to be very small.

Comment: Why do you use `pg.transform.rotozoom(self.origin_image, self.angle, 1)` instead of `self.image = pg.transform.rotate(self.origin_image, self.angle)`?

Comment: I don't know, it's more logical to use rotate. It doesn't change the result, but thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the size of the `Projectile` does not fall below a minimum size.:

<s>`self.damage = int(self.player.attack * min(self.player.chargeState, self.player.max_charge)**1.1)`</s>

```py
self.damage = max(5, int(self.player.attack * min(self.player.chargeState, self.player.max_charge)**1.1))
```

Comment: I tried, and tried a minimum size of 5x5 for the projectile image, but no change.

Comment: @AlanLauraux Sorry, but I cannot help you. I cannot reproduce the problem. It works fine form. However I don't have your images.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Using a smaller image is working. The original one was 512 x 512 pixels.